# Correct formula for the last page in pagination

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, aura, pagination, math

I make a pagination for lightning for my list of objects. First part is great. But when i get to the last page (`v.pages == v.page`) - something goes wrong. Values for the number of objects are completely wrong. How can I fix that?

```
 <aura:if isTrue="{!v.pages > v.page}">
      {!v.objectsPerPageList.length * v.page - (v.objectsPerPageList.length - 1)}/{!v.objectsPerPageList.length * v.page} Objects • page {!v.page}/{!v.pages}
           <aura:set attribute="else">
               {!v.objectsPerPageList.length * v.page - (v.objectsPerPageList.length - 1)}/{!v.objectsPerPageList.length * v.page} Objects • page {!v.page}/{!v.pages}
           </aura:set>
 </aura:if>
```

For example, when I have 10 records on the 1 page (our step) and all records = 13, I get: `1/10 Objects • page 1/2` and `4/6 Objects • page 2/2`. When I try it with 69 records = 7th page give me `55/63 Objects • page 7/7`.

Comment: How are your values "completely wrong"? What values are you getting vs expecting? Also, there's a missing `}`, which I presume is a just a typo. Please double-check your code, and [edit] your question to include any additional details.

Comment: Sorry. Thank you. I edited. For example, when I have 10 records on the 1 page (our step) and all records = 13, I get: `1/10 Objects • page 1/2` and `4/6 Objects • page 2/2`. When I try it with 69 records = 7th page give me `55/63 Objects • page 7/7`.

Comment: This is too much logic to have in your view layer. You should use an `<aura:attribute>` and calculate this value in your controller.